# How do I zoom in on the elbow plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

I am trying to find the eps value using technique calculates the average distance between each point and its k nearest neighbors and produces a k-distance elbow plot, But I don't know how to apply zoom-in on plot to see elbow clearly, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxc6h.png) and
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfIaZ.png)

Here is my code

```
neighbors = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6)
neighbors_fit = neighbors.fit(data_scale)
distances, indices = neighbors_fit.kneighbors(data_scale)
print(distances)
distances = np.sort(distances, axis=0)
distances = distances[:,1]
plt.plot(distances)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('eps')
plt.title('Elbow Method For Optimal eps')
plt.show()
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

To zoom in, you can change the axes range by `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()`

e.g.

```
plt.xlim([5000, 6000])
plt.ylim([0, 400])
```